# How do you auto mount hot swappable sata drives based on what sata port it is attached to?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sata, automount, hotswapping

I'm looking to auto mount hot swappable sata hdd's. There are multiple drives so identifying them via their UUID's is out of the question. I've searched but can't find a suitable option. The partitions on the drives may also be different so I can't make a symlink when sdb1 is entered for example as the mount point may be on a different partition like sdb5 on different HDD's. I've looked at mounting the partition to a label based on when something is plugged in to a specific sata port for example ata1 = "/media/disk1" ata2 = "/media/disk2", which would seem to be an ideal solution but haven't been able to get that to work.
I'm using lubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Why would identifying the drives via their UUID be out of the question? A disk has a unique UUID, which sounds exactly what you could use to differentiate drives.

Comment: There are potentially 250 drives possibly more keeping track of would end up being more complicated than manually mounting them.